# Как провайдер интернета идентифицирует клиентов по подключению через динамический IP

Tags: router, dhcp

Раньше у меня было подключение к интернет через PPPoE, сейчас мой провайдер больше не предоставляет такое подключение, а даёт подключение с помощью DHCP-сервера, выдавая моему роутеру динамический IP. В связи с этим меня интересует вопрос как тогда мой провайдер идентифицирует абонентов, ведь привязка идёт только по динамическому IP-адрессу ? Мой роутер подключается через Ethernet кабель к оптоволоконной сети провайдера.

Comment: dhcp провайдера выдает Вашему роутеру айпи по мак адресу роутера. Мак адрес обычно уникальный. Поэтому, провайдеру нужно только один раз привязать Ваш макадрес к Вам и все.

Comment: Теперь понятно. А если мне придётся поставить другой роутер, там же будет другой mac-адресс и пропадёт привязка IP адресса к MAC-адрессу.

Comment: @KoVadim Многие провайдеры уже не используют привязку по mac-адресу, а идентифицируют клиентов по порту коммутатора по которому пришел dhcp запрос и готовы выдавать адреса любым mac на данном порту (см. "option 82"). Либо выдают отдельный vlan на порт (клиента)

Comment: Коммутатор провайдера который стоит в подъезде и к которому подключается мой роутер. Спасибо за пояснения, теперь всё стало понятно.

Comment: на месте провайдера было бы наивно не использовать мак адрес. Как минимум пологировать. Можно конечно идентифицировать по порту коммутатора, но тут есть много проблем. Например, перетыкнули неудачно.